# Checking if a list has `any` NA - warning

Tags: r, list, warnings

I'm searching a way to check if a list has any NA elements, without using `for` loop. Also, if possible, understand the reason of the warning.

**This is my current context:** I'm using lapply to check if the all the files in, possible.existing.files,  indeed exists.

```
logic.vet <- lapply(possible.existing.files, file.exists)
```

The return will be a list of booleans.

So, I need to check if any of these elements are FALSE. In order to do so, I'm using `any`: `!any(logic.vet)`. However, it triggers a R warning, that tells:

```
Warning message:
In any(logic.vet) : coercing argument of type 'list' to logical
```

I've tried to work around this by *"casting"* the list to a vector, as: `as.vector(logic.vet)`, but the *cast* dosen't has effect in the structure of the variable. It continues to be a list.

Finally, is there any alternative for `any`? Currently, I'm using `options(warn = 0)` to hide the warning, but it doesn't seems right.

---

Just for the sake of providing an reproducible example, lets suppose that the `lapply` return a

```
list(TRUE, FALSE)
```

Now, how can I check if there is any false?

Comment: Have you tried `unlist(logic.vet)` instead of `as.vector()`?

Comment: @LAP I didn't even knew this function exists. This solves the "casting" problem

Comment: Do you need to know the position of the `FALSE` elements within the list?

Comment: @LAP **yes**,although it is not in the question,

Comment: @LAP, do you have any idea of what the warning is trying to warn me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
test <- list(T, F, T)

> test
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE
```

To see if there are `FALSE` elements, use

```
> !unlist(test)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Now, to get the position of all `FALSE` elements, just use

```
> which(!unlist(test))
[1] 2
```

To unselect `FALSE` elements, consequently use

```
possible.existing.files[-which(!unlist(logic.vet))]
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `lapply()`. `file.exists()` is vectorized, that is it accepts a vector as input.

```
files <- c("test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt", "test4.txt")
file.create(files)

# Just to check visually
list.files(pattern="^test")

possible.existing <- c("foo", files, "bar.zip")

# Any files not existing?
any(!file.exists(possible.existing))

# Which?
possible.existing[!file.exists(possible.existing)]

file.remove(files)
```